# Java Change Rounding

Tags: java

Im working on a cash register type application, i'm running into problems when separating dollars and cents. I can get dollars by its self but not cents. This is where I'm currently at.

change 126.7328
dollars 126
cents 7328

I want cents to just be 73 instead of 7328.

```
    String changeString = Double.toString(change); 
    String[] parts = changeString.split("\\.");
    String part2 = parts[1]; 
    double cents5 = Double.parseDouble(part2);
    int cents = (int)cents5
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: why "\\." and not just "."?

Comment: You should not be using floating point values for money. Use an integer or long value for cents, and do modulo 100 for change. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: Or else use BigDecimal (although beware the descent into madness when attempting comparisons and equals)

Comment: @JoePhilllips because `.` has a special meaning in *regex*. Note that `split(String)` expects a *regex* as argument.

Comment: @Christian It's clearly been too long since I've done any Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format your data using a NumberFormat object:

```
NumberFormat myCurrencyFormat = NumberFormat.currencyInstance();
String moneyString = myCurrencyFormat.format(change);
```

Or if you don't want to see the money symbol, use a DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String moneyString = decimalFormat.format(change);
```

Comment: but i just want it to be a 2 digit number like 73

Comment: @user3808597 Then do what someone already suggested... tackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency